# I have a HDD with data used on a Windows computer and I want to use it on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive

I am buying a new PC and plan to run Linux on it. I have an older PC which no longer works but I still need the data inside the HDD. Thing is, this old PC ran Windows. Do I

1. Have to use Windows on the new PC
2. Load up Linux on the new PC first, then after the setup and all, plug in the HDD
3. Just plug it in and do the setup.

I think when setting up a new OS on a machine you have to wipe the disk right? So I'm thinking the option would be 2.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install an OS you don't need to wipe the whole disk.

If I unterstood correctly you want to take the HDD from your old windows computer, connect it to your newly bought computer and install linux on it without losing the data which is already on the disk.

**Please note**: What I am describing here is a rather "low level" way of setting up your new computer. Making a mistake could result in loss of your data! It would be way easier and safer if you'd temporarily use a second disk for backup purposes.

My suggestion in the case of having only the one disk would be:

- Get your new computer and connect the hard disk to it
- Before installing any OS, boot from USB in order to rearrange partitions on your disk. You could use [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php) for that. The installation media of the linux distribution of your choice could also come with the necessary tools like parted.
- Shrink your existing windows partitions and make space for your linux OS installation plus some data partitions (especially useful if you intend to make your HDD a linux only disk eventually). I personally would prefer to make some free space in the beginning of the disk, but it technically doesn't matter as long as there is enough contiguous free space for your linux installation.
- Install your linux distro into the free space.
- Once your linux distro is up and running, you can mount your windows partitions (presumably NTFS) in read only mode and copy the data over to your linux partitions (ext4, btrfs, etc.). You don't need to mount in read only mode, but consider it as a safety net for your precious data until you've finished copying it all over to the new partitions.
- When you copied all your data, you can delete the windows partitions and use the space for your linux os.

We might be able to give more in-depth/specific instructions when you give more detailed information like the distro you want to use and what Windows version we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Windows to access the data. But you need some disk space where you can install linux. If you are buying a new PC it will probably ship with some SSD/HDD where you can install the OS. After installing linux you can mount the windows filesystem and access your old data. So yes, your proposed #2 would be the safest option to do so.
your first disk with linux installed will probably be named /dev/sda (sda1, sda2,.. will be the partitions on the disk) and if you plug in your old hdd it will probably be accessible as sdb. With the "list blockdevice" `lsblk` command you can find out how exactly your disks are named.
To access your data then you have to create a mountpoint first
`sudo mkdir /mnt/oldwindows`
and then mount the data partition of your windows disk

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sdb2 /mnt/oldwindows
```

this assumes that the data partition of your disk was the second and that it was formatted with the ntfs filesystem (this is a common setup for windows; first partition is a system partition, second the data, and a third for recovery. But that might differ. Just look at the lsblk output and pick the largest partition of the old disk). The "ro" part in the mount command will make the disk available in readonly mode, so you can't destroy anything.
If your disk is formatted in FAT32, the mount command looks like this

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o ro /dev/sdb2 /mnt/oldwindows
```

And to answer your last question: no you don't have to wipe a disk to setup a new OS necessarily but you'd need a usable partition with enough free space. The wipe and install option most installers give you is probably the most easy and convenient option for a linux beginner though.